# How to square each element of an array in Array class in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, perfect-square

Part of my code is as follows:

```
class Array
  def square!
    self.map {|num| num ** 2}
    self
  end
end
```

When I call:

```
[1,2,3].square!
```

I expect to get [1,4,9], but instead I get [1,2,3]. Why is this the case? When I call:

```
[1,2,3].map {|num| num ** 2}
```

outside of the class method, I get the correct answer.

Comment: Any reason (performance?) for destroying the original array (statement/imperative) instead of returning a new one (expression/functional)?

Comment: You use `map` to create an array of squares, and then just throw it away and return `self`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21), not [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

> `Array#map` -> *Invokes the given block once for each element of self.Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.*
>
> `Array#map!` -> *Invokes the given block once for each element of self, replacing the element with the value returned by the block.*

```
class Array
  def square!
    self.map! {|num| num ** 2}
  end
end

[1,2,3].square! #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: And you can leave out the `self` line. `self.map! {..}` already returns the array