# array.each return the same unchanged array after being modified.

Tags: ruby, iteration, each

Is there a way to return the new array?
I try to return the array of squared value [1, 4, 9] but it keeps returning [1, 2, 3] (the original array) Here is my code:

```
def square_array(array)
  array.each do |number| 
    number *= number
    puts number
  end
end

square_array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: "...it keeps returning..." brought a smile to my face. I'm sure that everyone reading this has had the same thought: "Maybe if I just run it again it will work".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to square each element of an array in Array class in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723386/how-to-square-each-element-of-an-array-in-array-class-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler version that does what you want:

```
def square_array(array)
  array.map do |number|
    number*number
  end
end
```

The problem with your code is that when you assign something to `number`, you're just assigning a value to a local variable, not some magic reference into an array.

Comment: Thanks, Linuxios, for an exercise I needed to use .each but I appreciate the help new approche.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

Using `Each` method

```
def square_array(array)
  temp = []
  array.each do |number| 
    temp <<  (number * number)
  end
  temp
end
```

Comment: Sachin, you can tighten this up by using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object): `def square_array(array); array.each_with_object([]) { |number, temp|  temp <<  (number * number) }; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you are right but @gregmarquet just want to use `each` for his exercise.

Comment: You're right. Greg hasn't been on SO long so may be new to Ruby, in which case the  use of `each_with_object` may be confusing. One possibility in such situations (when the code is short, as here) is to leave what you have then show the usual way the code would be written.

Answer (score 0):

When writing semantic ruby, it is best to use proper enumerable methods.  There is no need for the temporary variable in this case... we can use the *#map* method to return a new array that is the result of applying a function to each value in turn.  This is a core concept of the functional programming paradigm:

```
def square_array numbers
  numbers.map { |x| x ** 2 }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I fund a way, I just needed to push the result in a new array

```
    def square_array(array)
      new_array = []
      array.each do |num|
        squared_num = num ** 2
        new_array.push(squared_num)
      end
      return new_array
    end
```

Comment: I really think you should consider `map` or even `map!` instead, as it does what you want and is more concise.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the advice for the future, but I had to use .each for the purpose of the exercice.